# Batch remove artist and album name from MP3 files

Tags: mp3, id3, metadata-editor

I am looking for a software that can batch remove (i.e. do hundreds of files at once) only the artist name and album name, but leave the other MP3 ID3 tags, i.e. album art and song name.

I have found software that removes everything, but have not found anything with options of what to remove/leave intact.

I have also tried using the Windows file explorer to edit the tags to something, but that hasn't worked for some odd reason.

Would prefer FLOSS, on any system really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple [python](https://www.python.org/) script should do the job nicely with the [mp3-tagger](https://github.com/artcom-net/mp3-tagger).

On windows you would need to install python and then use `pip install mp3-tagger`

Then something like:

```
import os
import mp3_tagger
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):  # Assuming you would like to do all the files below the current directory
    for fn in files:
        if fn.lower().endswith('.mp3'):
            mp3 = mp3_tagger.MP3File(os.path.join(root, fn))
            del mp3.artist
            del mp3.album 
            mp3.save()
```

The above should work on most platforms and the tools are free, gratis & open source.